# How to send encrypted parameters to the node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

In my MEAN stack project on my client side I am retrieving data from the node server I am passing router parameters to the API router path and the server sends me data according to parameters. Everything is working fine but I want to send encrypted parameters to the server and then it has to decrypt at server side and according to encrypted parameters it has to give me a response

**My client side code:**

```
getRecentlyAddedPosts(limit, lastAmount){
    return this.http.get<any>(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/limit/${limit}/lastAmount/${lastAmount}`)
      .pipe(map((postData) => {
        return postData.map(post => {
          return {
            id: post._id,
            type: post.type,
            title: post.title,
            datetime: post.datetime,
            thumbnail: post.thumbnail,
            tags: post.tags,
            streamingLinks: post.streamingLinks,
            downloadingLinks: post.downloadingLinks,
            information: post.information,
            studioName: post.studioName,
          };
        });
      }));
  }
```

Comment: why? when ssl will take care of mitm.

Comment: Or use POST. Client side encryption is weak.